# How do I report a duplicate location on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I work for a company which has two duplicate entries on Google Maps listed under slightly different names. Both of these entries list different addresses, which has caused some confusion for people trying to find our office.

To fix the issue, I would like to merge both locations into a single entry. Unfortunately, selecting "*Report a data problem*" on either location doesn't give me the option to report duplicates.

**Is there a way to report duplicate locations on Google Maps?**

Answer (score 1):

Try following the instructions on [this help page](https://support.google.com/business/answer/4669139?hl=en).

Before you remove a duplicate:

Make sure that you're not removing the location that's already been verified, or else you'll need to verify it again.
Update the location you want to keep with any crucial information from the location you want to remove. Once a location is removed, it can't be recovered.
To remove a duplicate location in your account:

Sign in to Google My Business. 
In your "Account summary," click Duplicate locations. 
Click into the location you want to remove.
Click "Delete this listing."
To remove multiple duplicate locations:

Sign in to Google My Business. 
In your "Account summary," click Duplicate locations. 
Check the box for each location you want to remove.
Click the three dot menu icon  and choose Remove.
Report duplicate locations on Google Maps
To report a duplicate location on Google Maps:

Open Google Maps.
Find the location you want to report.
Click Suggest an edit.
Mark the location as "Place is permanently closed or has never existed."
Select "Duplicate" as the reason.
Click Submit.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can suggest an edit to the wrong place.  Just find the wrong place on the  Google maps app and click the 'three dots' button at the right top. Find "suggest an edit" sub menu and click 'Place has permanently  closed or moved or doesn't exist'

Your changed will be checked and applied after few days.